# Problem adding area target database in Vuforia area target

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have created area target with iPad's lidar and downloaded the latest Vuforia version 10.8 in my unity 2021.3 project. After adding ARCamera, when I add area target from Vuforia engine it shows me to add the area target button
[Add Area target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tPEZ.png)
and when I click the button it is taking me to the Unity landing page and asks me to register as a vuforia developer, but I am already registered.
[Register for Vuforia developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DS83.png)
Can anyone please help me out with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for the problem on my own so replying to this so if someone else got this issue, they can also get their problem solved.
Basically, you need to first import the database to add it to the area target so import your database, and your problem will get solved.